# Ошибка при выводе эмодзи

Tags: python, aiogram, emoji

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('УИИИИ! ПРИВЕТСТВУЮ ТЕБЯ НА ИНТЕНСИВЕ "ЗАРЯДИСЬ НА УСПЕХ"\n', emoji.emojize(':high_voltage:')
'Что делать дальше?\n\n'
'1. Обязательно подпишись на канал, где будут отправляться задания\n'
'2. Ежедневно выполняй задания и заряжай свою батарейку\n'
'3. В конце интенсива, один из тех, кто заряжен на 100%, получит супер приз\n'
'4. Задания будут приниматься до 23.00\n\n'

'Закрепи канал интенсива и чат бот, чтобы не пропустить задания!\n\n'

'Жди новостей на канале :)')
```

Вот такая ошибка:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
Что делать?

Comment: Ну, просто написать корректное python-выражение? Если вы хотите выполнить конкатенацию строк, значит напишите между ними оператор `+`, а сейчас у вас между `emoji.emojize(':high_voltage:')` и `'Что делать дальше?\n\n'` не стоит никакой оператор, и конечно это является некорректным синтаксисом

Comment: И ещё я сильно не уверен, что перед `emoji.emojize` должна стоять запятая, а не тот же самый `+`

Answer (score 1):

**Я забыл запятую** , emoji.emojize(':high_voltage:')*здесь*
'Что делать дальше?\n\n'